# Include a php-file with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, include

I'm having a problem with a simple include statement and I have no idea what's causing it.

First I'm storing information about tables and columns in a file called   dbInit.php

which looks like this:

```
<?php

   $aTableNames = array (
   "tbl_crs" => "tbl_crs",
   "tbl_lct" => "tbl_lct",
   "tbl_prf" => "tbl_prf",
   "tbl_qst" => "tbl_qst",
   "tbl_uni" => "tbl_uni",
   "tbl_usr" => "tbl_usr"
   );

   $aAuxTableNames = array (
   "aux_crs_lct" => "aux_crs_lct",
   "aux_lct_prf" => "aux_lct_prf",
   "aux_uni_crs" => "aux_uni_crs"
   );

?>
```

Now I simply want to access these arrays from another file. So I included it like this:

```
include "Ini/dbInit.php";
```

So far so good. Now I want to use the values of the arrays like this:

```
$sTable1 = $aAuxTableNames["aux_uni_crs"];
$sTable2 = $aTableNames["tbl_crs"];
```

The directory looks like this:
[image: Directory]

How can I access these arrays in the way sown above?

Thanks so much in advance.

Best regards
Amnney

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually asking here

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I want to keep my code as global as possible. So I want to store almost every information in external files. Just like the file dbIni.php. So that I can change it in this include file once and it is change in the entire code. But for some reason I'm not able to access the arrays at all.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Is your main script able to find the included file? If you have error reporting set as AbraCadaver suggested, try putting an echo statement in your included file, to confirm it's being included.

Comment: You have told us what you have done but you haven't told us two critical pieces of information: (1) What happened? (2) What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: (1) When I included the file I received a message from the server telling me that the server was unable to load the resource (Status 500). (2) I expected that the server would load the file properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no issue implementing this. So basically This is what I did. I copied your structure by having an include file with the arrays, exactly as you have posted here. Then I created a test file on the root of my server. This test file was php as well and I did the include as normal. Created the new variables, and then print_r(''); the 2 new variables you created out and received no errors.

This is my dbinit.php file:

```
 <?php 
     $aTableNames = array (
     "tbl_crs" => "tbl_crs",
     "tbl_lct" => "tbl_lct",
     "tbl_prf" => "tbl_prf",
     "tbl_qst" => "tbl_qst",
     "tbl_uni" => "tbl_uni",
     "tbl_usr" => "tbl_usr"
     );

    $aAuxTableNames = array (
    "aux_crs_lct" => "aux_crs_lct",
    "aux_lct_prf" => "aux_lct_prf",
    "aux_uni_crs" => "aux_uni_crs"
    );
?>
```

Ok so exactly as yours is. Then I created my file on the root called testpage.php:

```
<?php

include('inc/dbinit.php');

$sTable1 = $aAuxTableNames["aux_uni_crs"];
$sTable2 = $aTableNames["tbl_crs"];

print_r($sTable1);
print_r($sTable2);


?>
```

My structure as indicated: [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDu1H.jpg)

Absolutely no issues running this or retrieving the data. Hope this helps.

Final Output: [Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xyGw.png)

Comment: Thank you for testing it. I just removed the file and recreated it and for some reason it works even though I didn't change a thing.

Comment: Absolutely, glad you were able to figure it out! I didn't see any errors and that's why I used print_r(); to see what the results were. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Ini/dbInit.php
<?php

return array(
    'aTableNames' => array(
        "tbl_crs" => "tbl_crs",
        "tbl_lct" => "tbl_lct",
        "tbl_prf" => "tbl_prf",
        "tbl_qst" => "tbl_qst",
        "tbl_uni" => "tbl_uni",
        "tbl_usr" => "tbl_usr"
    ),

   'aAuxTableNames' => array(
        "aux_crs_lct" => "aux_crs_lct",
        "aux_lct_prf" => "aux_lct_prf",
        "aux_uni_crs" => "aux_uni_crs"
    ),
);
```

In file, where you want to get **Ini/dbInit.php**

```
<?php

$config = include "Ini/dbInit.php";
$sTable1 = $config['aAuxTableNames']['aux_uni_crs']
$sTable2 = $config['aTableNames']['tbl_crs'];
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it works just fine. But for some reason mine is now working too. Thank you so much :)